# hadoop installation issue on fedora 24

Tags: hadoop

I have been following this tutorial  thttp://www.tecmint.com/install-configure-apache-hadoop-centos-7/ to set up hadoop on a virtual machine. However, when i try to start hadoop I am getting the follow error:

```
start-dfs.sh 

Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /opt/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now. It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'. 16/11/09 08:20:06 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable Starting namenodes on [master.hadoop.lan]
```

my Java JDK directory is JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_111

below is my configuration information in the .bash_profile file:

```
## JAVA env variables
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_111
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
## HADOOP env variables
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

my java home path in the hadoop-env.sh file is :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_111
```

Am I missing a configuration step?

Answer (score 0):

it's just a warning.

type `jps` and check whether namenode and datanode is running.

If you want to eliminate the warning, 
replace `export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"`
with

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -XX:-PrintWarnings -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

and execute bash